# Look for subsets of keywords in a Pandas Series (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, series

I'm working with Series that look pretty much like this:

```
l0 = ['smartphone', 'battery', 'case', 'grey', '10071852']
l1 = ['phone', 'new', 'charging', 'case', 'white']
l2 = ['tablet', 'phone', 'pin', 'adapter', 'ex766']
l3 = ['phone', 'silicon', 'case', 'brown']

mySeries = pd.Series([l0,l1,l2,l3])

print(mySeries)

0    [smartphone, battery, case, grey, 10071852]
1            [phone, new, charging, case, white]
2           [tablet, phone, pin, adapter, ex766]
3                  [phone, silicon, case, brown]
```

And I'm trying to search for keywords and sets of keywords that might be contained in each row (each list) of the Series. More specifically, let's say I want to find if a row in the Series contains the following keywords:

```
simple_keywords = {'case', 'adapter'}
```

But also find if the Series contains the following pairs of keywords:

```
double_keywords = {'battery case', 'charging case'}
```

To look for the simple_keywords, it seems to be easy. However, I want to look for the pairs as well, and make sure that if there is a pair like "battery case" I want it to return the pair of keywords, and not just "case".

Additionally, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d = {'Date': ['03/08/2014', '04/08/2014', '05/08/2014', '06/08/2014'], 'Product': ['none', 'none','none','none'],'Frequency': [5, 10, 1, 2]}
myDF = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(myDF)

         Date  Frequency Product
0  03/08/2014          5    none
1  04/08/2014         10    none
2  05/08/2014          1    none
3  06/08/2014          2    none
```

My end goal is to write in this dataframe (in the column Product) the corresponding keyword (or pair of keywords) that I have identified in the Series. Each row of the Series corresponds to the exact same row in the dataframe, which means that the order is very important. I want to see that the product "battery case", on August 3rd 2014, had the frequency of 5.

I tried to come up with some solution by separating the pairs of keywords, but it seems to be extremely slow and not so efficient as I have more than 350'000 rows in the Series I am working with (left it over night and it wasn't finished):

```
first_keywords = {'case', 'adapter'}
second_keywords = {'battery', 'charging'}    

mySeries_range = len(mySeries)

for i in range(mySeries_range):
        for x, y in [(x, y) for x in first_keywords for y in second_keywords]:
            if x in mySeries[i] and y in mySeries[i]:
                myDF.Product[i] = y + ' ' + x
            elif x in mySeries[i] and y not in mySeries[i]:
                myDF.Product[i] = x
```

And the final result that I wish to obtain is:

```
         Date  Frequency        Product
0  03/08/2014          5   battery case
1  04/08/2014         10  charging case
2  05/08/2014          1        adapter
3  06/08/2014          2           case
```

If someone could help me that would be great. Apologies if my code is not so pretty... Trying to get better!

Comment: Just to make sure I get the first point. You'd like to be able to output the actual intersection (like a `set()` intersection) between your series list and some products, right ? That is, find if one product occurs, or two occur, and output these matches.

Comment: @Arnaud yes, exactly. For a list of products like "case", "adapter", "battery case" I would like to see if they occur in any sub of my series, and if they do, output them to my dataframe.

Comment: Alright. When looking for "battery case" do you look for co occurrence of "battery" and "case" or do you look for exact match "battery case" ? Sorry, trying to get it right :)

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying to help! Yes that's right, I want the co-occurence of both "battery" and "case", not necessarily the exact match "battery case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate as many combination as you want from the wors in the list of `mySeries`this way:

```
import itertools
df_comb = pd.concat([mySeries.apply(lambda x: [" ".join(l) 
                     for l in list(itertools.combinations(x,max_len))
                     ]).rename(max_len) 
                     for max_len in [1,2]],axis=1).astype(str)
```

This is the result:

```
>>> df_comb                                             1  \
0  [smartphone, battery, case, grey, 10071852]   
1          [phone, new, charging, case, white]   
2         [tablet, phone, pin, adapter, ex766]   
3                [phone, silicon, case, brown]   

                                                   2  
0  [smartphone battery, smartphone case, smartpho...  
1  [phone new, phone charging, phone case, phone ...  
2  [tablet phone, tablet pin, tablet adapter, tab...  
3  [phone silicon, phone case, phone brown, silic...
```

Now let's make the dicts of words a list so it is easier to iterate:

```
simple_keywords = ['case', 'adapter']
double_keywords = ['battery case', 'charging case']
```

Then you can count the elements this way:

```
>>> pd.concat([df_comb.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).str.count(w),axis=0)[len(' '.split(w))].rename(w) 
for w in simple_keywords],axis=1)
   case  adapter
0     1        0
1     1        0
2     0        1
3     1        0

>>> pd.concat([df_comb.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).str.count(w),axis=0)[len(w.split(' '))].rename(w) for w in double_keywords],axis=1)

  battery case  charging case
0             1              0
1             0              1
2             0              0
3             0              0
```

Or we can do it iterating this way:

```
df_count = pd.DataFrame()
for list_of_keywords in [simple_keywords, double_keywords]:
    df_count_temp = pd.concat([df_comb.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).str.count(w),
                               axis=0)[len(w.split(' '))].rename(w) 
                               for w in list_of_keywords],axis=1)
    df_count = pd.concat([df_count, df_count_temp],axis=1)
```

The count will be then:

```
>>> df_count

   case  adapter  battery case  charging case
0     1        0             1              0
1     1        0             0              1
2     0        1             0              0
3     1        0             0              0
```

You can get the final count this way:

```
>>> df_count.sum(axis=0).to_frame()

               0
case           3
adapter        1
battery case   1
charging case  1
```

You can create a function to apply this to each day's entries.

```
def my_func(mySeries, keywords =  [['case', 'adapter'] ,['battery case', 'charging case']]):
    import itertools
    keyword_lengths = [len(k[0].split(' ')) for k in keywords]
    df_comb = pd.concat([mySeries.apply(lambda x: [" ".join(l) 
                         for l in list(itertools.combinations(x,max_len))
                         ]).rename(max_len) 
                         for max_len in keyword_lengths],axis=1).astype(str)

    df_count = pd.DataFrame()
    for list_of_keywords in keywords:
        df_count_temp = pd.concat([df_comb.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x).str.count(w),
                                   axis=0)[len(w.split(' '))].rename(w) 
                                   for w in list_of_keywords],axis=1)
        df_count = pd.concat([df_count, df_count_temp],axis=1)

    return df_count
```

Imagine this is your pd.Series:

```
>>> newSeries 
2014-03-08    [smartphone, battery, case, grey, 10071852]
2014-03-08            [phone, new, charging, case, white]
2014-03-08           [tablet, phone, pin, adapter, ex766]
2014-03-08                  [phone, silicon, case, brown]
2014-04-08            [phone, new, charging, case, white]
2014-04-08                           [tablet, phone, pin]
2014-04-08                               [phone, adapter]
dtype: object



>>> my_func(newSeries)

            case  adapter  battery case  charging case
2014-03-08     1        0             1              0
2014-03-08     1        0             0              1
2014-03-08     0        1             0              0
2014-03-08     1        0             0              0
2014-04-08     1        0             0              1
2014-04-08     0        0             0              0
2014-04-08     0        1             0              0
```

Then you can play with the dataframe returned grouping by dates and counting the elements. This way you will obtain the appearances by date:

```
>>> df_appearances= my_func(newSeries).reset_index().groupby('index'
                     ).sum().T.unstack().reset_index()

>>> df_appearances.columns = ['Date', 'Product', 'Frequency']

>>> df_appearances

        Date        Product  Frequency
0 2014-03-08           case          3
1 2014-03-08        adapter          1
2 2014-03-08   battery case          1
3 2014-03-08  charging case          1
4 2014-04-08           case          1
5 2014-04-08        adapter          1
6 2014-04-08   battery case          0
7 2014-04-08  charging case          1
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response, I like your solution. However, one question, how did you create the newSeries with the dates? I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: And also, what would be the way to transfer the column "Date" of myDF dataframe and copy it to mySeries, so it looks like your newSeries? Thanks.

Comment: You can create a date for example, this way: `pd.to_datetime('03/08/2014')`, then you can assign an index to mySeries, `mySeries = pd.Series([l0,l1,l2,l3],index=['03/08/2014','03/08/2014','03/08/2014','03/08/2014'])`, and then convert it to datetime this way:  `mySeries.index = pd.to_datetime(mySeries.index)`

Comment: Now, `df_appearances` could be your `myDF` since it matches its function and structure. Just name it `myDF`.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part about finding the keywords that match in your `Series()` I'd suggest the following :

```
mySeries.apply(lambda l: " ".join(e for e in keywords if all(keyword in l for keyword in e.split())))
```

Sorry for the phrasing which should (must) be improved. But the idea is just check if **all** elements in your input strings (split by default `" "`) are found in the Series row. If they do, then return them.

You may use that with `simple_keywords` or `double_keywords` (instead of the `keywords` in my line, I guess it works.

With `simple_keywords` :

```
0       case
1       case
2    adapter
3       case
```

With `double_keywords` :

```
0     battery case
1    charging case
2                 
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas Vectorized method

```
df=pd.Series([l0,l1,l2,l3])
df=df.apply(''.join)

df[df.str.contains('batterycase')]='batterycase'
df[df.str.contains('chargingcase')]='chargingcase'
df[df.str.contains('case')&~(df.str.contains('chargingcase') |(df.str.contains('batterycase')))]='case'
df[df.str.contains('adapter')]='adapter'

d = {'Date': ['03/08/2014', '04/08/2014', '05/08/2014', '06/08/2014'],'Frequency': [5, 10, 1, 2]}
myDF = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

myDF['Product']=df
```

Result

```
        Date       Frequency       Product
0     03/08/2014          5    batterycase
1     04/08/2014         10    chargingcase
2     05/08/2014          1       adapter
3     06/08/2014          2          case
```